# How/What hostname do I use on my command line to access my Github?

Tags: github, ssh, command, putty

I am new to command line and have no idea how to use. I have Putty command line and would like to connect to my GitHub. Putty asks for a "Hostnamne/IP address". I do not know what to insert so it can work. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY isn't something that you would use to connect directly to GitHub. It is an *SSH* client, but you need a *Git* client. Since GitHub doesn't provide interactive SSH, PuTTY won't be of much use.

I'm going to assume you're on Windows since that's where PuTTY is most often used. You can install the [latest official release of Git for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io/), but it's probably worth installing [one of the recent 2.x prereleases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) instead. These will be the official versions very shortly.

Once you have Git installed you should be able to run "Git Bash", which will drop you into a command line. At this point you can use [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) to clone an existing repository, [`git init`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) to create a brand new one, or any number of other things. You'll probably want to find a tutorial or read [a book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) before going much further.

If you'd prefer a graphical Git client there are [many options](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis).